# How to set Margin Left ,Margin top,Margin right and Margin Bottom alignment for popup window dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow

I  am currently doing an android application that contains a popup window named as mypopup. It contains a Image button and four textviews. i want to align the popup window dynamically with margin top,margin bottom,margin left and margin right parameters..In my code setmargin method is not working..please anybody help me to do this...

Comment: Add some codes so that we can understand.

Comment: for pop you are using Alert or pop up window ? for solution you should provide some code

Answer (score 0):

It depends that which layout you are using. Below example places a RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout.

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutParent;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams margin = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
margin.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 7); //7px bottom margin

//create the linear and the relative layouts

//...add other stuff here...

// Add view with its margins
linearLayoutParent.addView(relativeLayout, margin);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0,0, 5, 0);
```